# How to remove an extra field from an employee when I assign to the Employee Details object

Tags: typescript

How to remove an extra field from an employee when I assign to the Employee Details object.

```
 class EmployeeDetails{
        public empNo:number;
        public  firstName:string;
        public lastName:string;
    }
    var employee = {
        empNo:5,
        firstName:'xyz',
        lastName:'abc',
        department:'development'
    }
    var emp = new EmployeeDetails();
    emp=employee;
console.log(emp);
```

**output should be ::**

```
{  
"empNo":5,            
"firstName":"xyz",
"lastName":"abc"
}
```

Comment: I don't think `var emp = new EmployeeDetails();
    emp=employee;` does what you think it does. Although `emp` is typed as `EmployeeDetails` since you assign an object literal to it, it will not be an instance of `EmployeeDetails`

Comment: what if 
let emp:EmployeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();

Comment: you can create a specific method that return the value as you want , example toJSON() , this method will return only the values that you want to export